# Best way to pass testng parameters from commandline

Tags: testng, data-driven-tests

What is the best way to pass parameters to testng from commandline .I searched the entire testng javadoc but I could not find any useful info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Environment Variables by adding one in the command line with `-Dpropertyname=value` syntax and get value by using `System.getenv('propertyname');`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.System.getenv('propertyname') did not work but System.getProperty('propertyname') worked perfectly...